# mysql select by sections, how to get over record gap?

Tags: mysql

here is my scenario:
i have over 100,000 records, with varchar id as the primary key, but the id is not continuous: there is a gap, like 1,2,3...2000, 3500,3501,3502....
i need to query this table by sections, each with 1000 records, but there is a problem with the sql:
select * from mytable where rec_id between 1 and 1000
if the query fell into the gap (2000 -- 3500), it will return nothing, but how do i get to know that if the table is finished or the query is just in the gap?

and by all means, if you have any other solutions, please share with me, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `limit` and `offset` for this purpose:

This query will return the first 1000 registers:

```
select * from mytable limit 1000
```

This one will return registers from 1001 to 2000:

```
select * from mytable limit 1000 offset 1000
```

and so on.